# Convert cURL cmd to PHP

Tags: php, curl

could you please help me with converting cURL command to PHP:

```
curl -S -s --cacert GeoTrust_Primary_CA.pem-X -X POST -F "type=xml" -F
"token= aGEMQB9Idh35fxxxxxxxxxxxxxQwyGlQ" -F "file=@C:\batch.xml"
https://www.fio.cz/ib_api/rest/import/> server_response.xml 2>error.log
type error.log
```

exec() does not work.

Thank you very much.

Petr

Comment: Try https://curlconverter.com/php/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) php function ? 
You can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) all the options to process your request. For example, you can start from this :

```
    $request = curl_init( $URL );
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);
```